Woman goes after serial killer who may have killed her sister
I'm looking to find a film I watched in the late 90's possibly early 00's.  A woman goes in hunt of a serial killer. I think he may have killed her sister. It turns out that she has no leads what so ever until near the end when she discovers it's a man who has been in a wheelchair throughout the whole film, pretending to be disabled

Reminiscent of The Alphabet Killer with Eliza Dushku, though the year and the sister bit don't fit.

If my answer is right (which I think it is) please mark it as correct. Thanks.

Like Walt said, your description does bear similarities to The Alphabet Killer (2008), though not the sister bit.

Megan Paige (Eliza Dushku) is an investigator for the Rochester Police
  Department investigating the murder of a young girl named Carla
  Castillo. Her body was found in the nearby village of Churchville, New
  York with white cat hair on it. Against opposition of her colleagues
  and partner/boyfriend Kenneth Shine (Cary Elwes), Megan insists that
  the murder is a work of a serial killer. Despite Megan’s considerable
  efforts she fails to catch the killer. Stress and obsession of the
  investigation causes Megan to hallucinate the victim's image. She
  ultimately has a nervous breakdown after being kicked off the case and
  tries to commit suicide.
Following two years of medical treatment and attending a support group
  headed by a wheelchair-bound man named Richard Ledge (Timothy Hutton),
  Megan rejoins the police department in an office job.

